# Why is my Jquery Ajax request not working error:Undefined index: ProID?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Details: Hey guys i searched all over for a solution to my problem but to no avail please don't report the question until you understand my problem. I have a index page which contains sql which i pulled to add products to my page and wanted to create an ajax request with the id of each product which is echoed in the button to create a product detail page however i cant seem to get the Product ID to post on the product detail page any help towards the right direction will be appreciated.Thank you!

> Exact Error: Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\includes\product_detail.php on line 7

Things I've tried:
Changing 'post' to 'POST'
Add a datatype
and thats all the errors i see

**Jquery Code :**

```
function detail(ProID){
var data = {"id" : ProID};
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: '/website/includes/product_detail.php',   
 method : "post",
 data:  data,
 success : function(data){

    window.open("includes/product_detail.php","_self");

},
 error:function(){
    alert("Something when wrong!");
}
});

 }
</script>
```

**HTML/php code:**

```
    <?php 
    require_once 'dbconnect/dbconnect.php';
      include 'includes/head.php';
      include 'includes/header.php';
      include 'includes/navigation.php';
      include 'includes/footer.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE featured = 1";
    $featured = $db->query($sql);
?>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div  class="main-body">
            <h2 class="center-header">Featured Products</h2>
            <?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)): ?>
                <div class="row_one">

                    <div class="product-one" >
                        <h4><?= $product['ProName']; ?></h4>
                        <a href="includes/product_detail.php">
                        <img class="product_img_one"src="<?= $product['Image']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['ProName']; ?>">
                        </a>
                        <p>List Price:<s class="list_price">$<?= $product['List_Price'];?></s></p>
                        <p>Sales Price:$<?= $product['Price'];?></p>
                        <button type="button" class="product-detail" 
                                onclick= "detail(<?= $product["ProID"]; ?>)">Details</button>

                </div>
             <?php endwhile; ?>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Where the request is supposed to work:

```
<?php 
    require_once '../dbconnect/dbconnect.php';
    include 'head.php';
    include 'header.php';
    include "navigation.php";
    include "footer.php";
    $id = $_POST["ProID"];
    $id = (int)$id;
    $sql = "SElECT * FROM products WHERE ProID = '$id'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
```

Comment: change  `$id = $_POST["ProID"];` to  `$id = $_POST['id'];`

Comment: @dass I tried this already it didn't work thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: why using  `jQuery.ajax({` ?? use `$.ajax({`

Comment: @dass I thought is was the same as $.ajax but i also tried changing it just now and it still didn't help the error.

Comment: the code still remain `$id = $_POST['id'];` or u changed back??

Comment: @dass yes i left it that way and also tried it how it was before.

Comment: after changed the code to `$id = $_POST['id'];` what is error showing??

Comment: The errors is the same "Notice: Undefined index: id" so the ProID just changes to id

Comment: `var data = {"id" : ProID};` remove the double quote in id

Comment: I tried removing it still didn't work

Comment: `dataType:'json'` add this code below `data:data`

Comment: When i add this i get my error message "something went wrong"

Comment: the error message because of you have return nothing from product_details.php

Comment: Well i want to get the productid from my index.php file do you think my url might be wrong?

Comment: `$result = $db->query($sql);   $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` your mixing msqli OO and mysqli procedural.. tats y u get error message

Comment: The $sql is a variable and not a mixture of sql and sqli where did you see i mixed it? in the example you gave the '$sql' is a variable.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp.. look at this tutorial.. and find the difference between mysqli OO and mysqli procedural

Comment: Ok thanks for all of the suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
 $id = $_POST["id"]; not  $id = $_POST["ProID"];
```

on your product_detail.php page

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Arup but my id in my database is ProID.I tried it anyway and it didn't work.

Comment: can you please check ProID values are fetching properly from database . use print_r($product); next to while loop

Comment: Hey Arup i tried this and also tried using and alert to show me the ID each time i click a product detail button to show the id of that product and it shows the id

Answer (score 0):

I doubt in the method of jquery ajax use `method  : 'POST'` post should be in capital letters;

```
// this is what i am using as template for sending request after organizing data in json format...
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "submit.php",
        data: {Product_Name: "theProduct_Name", Price: 500, "Product_ID": "theProduct_ID"},
        success : function(responseText)
                  {
                    alert('success to reach backend');
                    // you can console the responseText and do what ever you want with responseText
                    console.log(responseText);
                  },
        error : function(jqXHR, status, error)
                {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) 
                    {
                        alert('Not connected.\nPlease verify your network connection.');
                    } 
                    else if (jqXHR.status == 404) 
                    {
                        alert ('The requested page not found. [404]');
                    } 
                    else if (jqXHR.status == 500) 
                    {
                        alert ('Internal Server Error [500].');
                    } 
                    else if (exception === 'parsererror') 
                    {
                        alert ('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                    } 
                    else if (exception === 'timeout') 
                    {
                        alert ('Time out error.');
                    } 
                    else if (exception === 'abort') 
                    {
                        alert ('Ajax request aborted.');
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        alert ('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                    }
                 }
      });
```

Comment: let me know if it didnot work for you if worked please accept as an answer... ?

Comment: it didnt work thanks for the suggestion though. Appreciated!